# change pandas crossstab dataframe into plain table format:

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got aggregate dataframe through following pandas crosstab. However, I'd like to columns' format like this:

```
id         ymdh            A11      A12      A15      A16   
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I change the original dataframe into my desired format?

```
* Original output dataframe:     

df = pd.crosstab(df.ymdh, df_data.id, margins=False,     
                      values=df.duration, dropna=False,
                      normalize='columns',
                      aggfunc=[np.sum]).reset_index().fillna(0)


            ymdh       sum                                                     
id                     A11      A12      A15      A16       
----------------------------------------------------------
0      2016040100  0.000000  0.002222  0.049398  0.018077  
1      2016040101  0.003354  0.004141  0.078531  0.015131 
2      2016040102  0.001397  0.002424  0.000633  0.001473
```

Comment: Can you add sample of data for creates `pd.crosstab` ?

Comment: Or maybe help change `aggfunc=[np.sum]` to `aggfunc='sum'`

Comment: hahaha.....Thank you so much! ^^;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) with `sum`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.ymdh, df_data.id, margins=False,     
                      values=df.duration, dropna=False,
                      normalize='columns',
                      aggfunc='sum').reset_index().fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

To me this question topic (as on 2019-08-20: *change pandas crossstab dataframe into plain table format*) sounds rather misleading. Also, the fact that 600+ people have viewed this question, perhaps they were also looking for something else.

In case you are looking for converting a crosstab into a stacked dataframe please check out this discussion: [Converting a pandas crosstab into a stacked dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57583269/converting-a-pandas-crosstab-into-a-stacked-dataframe)

An example of crosstab to stacked dataframe could be a regular table with two columns:

```
col-1: consists of row labels,
col-2: consists of column labels of the crosstab.
```

Comment: i personally was looking for something more like this then the question you suggested